# SQL (Access): Multiple values per "ID" - Store as TRUE unless any FALSE

Tags: sql, ms-access

Good afternoon!
I have recently come across an issue that I am hoping can be solved with your help. Our system is [sadly] ran on Access (2007). I have decent experience with SQL and elect to use this method for most of queries rather than the Design View. However, this is the issue I have come across recently:

A table (with its own primary key of course) contains the ParticipantID and Records. This table may contain multiple records per person due to having events at various locations. With this information we track whether or not each record is within our system already due to the location falling under our large "umbrella" (Internal). To make it look simple, it looks something like this, ignoring the primary key as we only care about the participant ID.

```
ParticipantID     Internal
1                 -1
1                 -1
2                 0
3                 -1
3                 -1
3                 0
4                 -1
4                 0
```

I want to be able to say if ANY of the records of a participant are not Internal (eg. =0), then in this query's results, store it as 0.
Hence, the results table would look something like:

```
ParticipantID     Internal
1                 -1
2                 0
3                 0
4                 0
```

Does this make sense? Thank you in advance!

Comment: A few questions. Do you need this to be done with a single query? Also, is it a one time operation, or something that will happen fairly frequently?

Comment: Thanks all. I clearly was thinking about this the wrong way - Max is an obvious answer; this is what happens when you aren't thinking in binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Max:

```
SELECT internal.ParticipantID, Max(internal.Internal) AS MaxOfInternal
FROM internal
GROUP BY internal.ParticipantID;
```

I built the above using the query design window.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Hé,hé cackle etc :)

Comment: Wow. I'm a moron! High five. So simple, cheers.
This is what happens when you switch languages; I was thinking of this is a hash and going about it that way and how to examine the values blah blah blah. Genius. Occam's Razor...

Answer (score 0):

If the values  Internal can be only 0 and -1 the following may help

```
Select ParticipantID,max(internal) from thetable
Group by ParticipantID
```